# Error when calling Dask groupby with custom aggregate

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask

The following error occurs when running the below example test, what am I doing wrong?

> Error: Exception('Column(s) id already selected',)

Code:

```
import unittest
import dask
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

class TestDaskCustomAgg(unittest.TestCase):

    def mode(self, x):
        val = pd.Series.mode(x)
        if val.empty:
            return np.NaN
        return val[0]
  
    def test_get_transactions(self):
        df = dask.datasets.timeseries()
        custom_agg = dd.Aggregation('custom_agg', agg=lambda x: self.mode(x), chunk=lambda x0: self.mode(x0))
        df.groupby('name').agg(custom_agg).compute()
```

Comment: Please give the complete traceback

Comment: You appear to be calling `Series.mode` on a dataframe? What do you want the output to be here - the mode of strings, times and floating numbers is not a very useful value.